# How to render video in browser before uploading it using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, video, upload

I want to render the video in the browser before its uploaded to server.I have done the code in angular js.

here is my codes 
html(jade)

```
input(type='file' ng-file-select="readURL(this)" accept='video/*')
video(width='320', height='240', controls='')
source(id ='blah' src='#', type='video/mp4')
```

javascript:

```
$scope.readURL = (input) ->
    console.log "inside"
    if input.files and input.files[0]
        console.log 'hello'
        reader = new FileReader
        reader.onload = (e) ->
            console.log e.target.result
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result)
            return

        reader.readAsDataURL input.files[0]
    return
```

Thank's in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive here, if so, the solution is simple:

the html part:

```
<div ng-app='theModule' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <button ngf-select ng-model="files"  accept='video/*' >select video</button>
    <video controls ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-accept="'video/*'" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

the js part:

```
angular.module('theModule', ['ngFileUpload']).controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload){
}]);
```

if you want to listen to file changes, you can add  `ngf-change="...`

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aprteom/)

Comment: @Rkn does the browser support opening `3gp` videos?

Comment: Yes. it support opening 3gp.